# Fetch content from rich text field

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, gatsby, contentful, richtext

I am following [this](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/rich-text-and-gatsby/) documentation to render rich text from Contentful.

So far I have installed `gatsby-source-contentful`, now I am querying the rich text content with a graphQL query, before adding to my template.

**Issue:** I cannot query the `references` field.

From my understanding there was a recent **[breaking change](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/25249)** that required the `raw` subfield to be queried...but unfortunately I can't query any subfield within `raw`.

I am not sure what the issue can possibly be.

**Query**

```
{
  allContentfulArticle {
    edges {
      node {
        content {
          raw
          references {
            ... on ContentfulArticle {
              contentful_id
              title
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Error message**
[image]

Comment: I can't get why your error message talks about type "ContentfulArticleContent", maybe this is something to dig into

Answer (score 0):

`references` stands for a [reference content model](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/data-model/), which is a way of retrieving data from another entry by adding them one by one in the main entry. The guide is assuming that you have followed exactly the same structure but it's not needed. If you don't have a `reference` content model, don't query it. The GraphQL playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`) will show you all the available queryable fields.

In addition, the guide is using a GraphQL fragment on `ContentfulAsset`, not on `ContentfulArticle`, again, is assuming that you've added an asset entry for your article, don't query it if it's not available or you don't have it. You just need to customize the query for your use-case and your own fields.

```
{
  allContentfulArticle {
    edges {
      node {
        content {
          raw
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the query above, you should be able to gather all the raw data from the rich text model. However, you need to add a transformer in your Gatsby project, which will render and parse the correct component for each type of rich text (bold text, embedded entries, links, code, etc).

```
import { BLOCKS, MARKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"
​
const Bold = ({ children }) => <span className="bold">{children}</span>
const Text = ({ children }) => <p className="align-center">{children}</p>
​
const options = {
  renderMark: {
    [MARKS.BOLD]: text => <Bold>{text}</Bold>,
  },
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <Text>{children}</Text>,
    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => {
      return (
        <>
          <h2>Embedded Asset</h2>
          <pre>
            <code>{JSON.stringify(node, null, 2)}</code>
          </pre>
        </>
      )
    },
  },
}

   renderRichText(node.bodyRichText, options)
```

More details [here](https://github.com/contentful/rich-text/tree/master/packages/rich-text-react-renderer) and in the [`gatsby-source-contentful` docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/#rendering).
​

Comment: I've copied and pasted this but I'm getting unexpected character erros throughout the code, which is strange. Even with this code https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/rich-text-and-gatsby/

Comment: Can you debug a little bit more? What "unexpected" errors?