# Contentful render long text

Tags: javascript, graphql, content-management-system, gatsby, contentful

I'm figuring out how to render standard ***long text***, but having issues.

Please take a look at my query, that is working when ran in the graphQL playground.

```
{
  allContentfulArticle {
    nodes {
      title
      slug
      para {
        para
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my article.js file

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
 

const Article = props => (
  <div>
    <header>
      <h1>{props.data.site.siteMetadata.title}</h1>
    </header>

    <main>
      <h1>{props.data.contentfulArticle.title}</h1>
    </main>

    <footer>
    <p>{props.data.site.siteMetadata.author}</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
)

export default Article

export const query = graphql`
  query Article($id: String) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
        description
        author
      }
    }
    contentfulArticle(id: { eq: $id }) {
      title
      subtitle
      slug
      para {
        para
      }
    }
  }
`
```

The strange thing is that I can render the `title` easily which is a simialir content type - just short.

I can see my `title`, `slug` and other metadata fields being displayed on localhost, but not the `para` paragraph.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not rendering your long text field despite your GraphQL query looks perfect. Just use:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
 

const Article = props => (
  <div>
    <header>
      <h1>{props.data.site.siteMetadata.title}</h1>
    </header>

    <main>
      <h1>{props.data.contentfulArticle.title}</h1>
    </main>
    <p>Your long text is: {props.data.contentfulArticle.para.para}</p>
    <footer>
    <p>{props.data.site.siteMetadata.author}</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
)

export default Article

export const query = graphql`
  query Article($id: String) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
        description
        author
      }
    }
    contentfulArticle(id: { eq: $id }) {
      title
      subtitle
      slug
      para {
        para
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks - not quite sure how I missed that! I have chosen to render long text, because I had major issues with render rich text using the new `raw` subfield. Would you mind taking a look at this issue? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65751495/fetch-content-from-rich-text-field

Comment: Sure, I will. If the issue has been solved please accept the answer to close the issue :)